# How can I Insert a person in a database table with unlimited records ( addresses for example ) and a unique ID for this client only using asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a crud application with visual studio 2022 and SQL server using ASP.Net core web application (framework) and C#.

-I need to create 2 tables, one for persons and the other for addresses.
-To Link both tables.
-Each person must have many addresses and a unique person ID so when i insert I can insert the same person once with many addresses but his ID is unique for him only.

Please I need help. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class PersonsData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        SqlConnection sqlcon1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLOCALDB;Initial Catalog=personsDB;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            sqlcon1.Open();

            SqlCommand commToCheckpID = new SqlCommand("SELECT pID, pname FROM addresses, persons WHERE addresses.pID = persons.pname");
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(commToCheckpID);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (TextBox1.Text == TextBox3.Text)
            {

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('ID Already Exist');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                String query1 = "insert into addresses (address, pID) VALUES ('" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandText = query1;
                cmd1.Connection = sqlcon1;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                String query = "insert into persons (pname) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = sqlcon1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Data has been inserted successfully');", true);
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                TextBox3.Text = "";

                sqlcon1.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at Entity Framework yet?

Comment: yes, I did but I'm still lost, can't solve this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: All database access happens through SQL and ADO.NET. Even if you use an ORM on top. like Entity Framework. The ASP.NET Core Getting Started tutorial shows how to work with databases.

Comment: Here is where I reached, My question is update above

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a table with persons and one with addresses and a thrird table with relations, so person ID 1 has Address ID 1 and address ID 2 and address ID 23.

Afterwards, you need a join statement for retrieving all address of a giver person

A hacky approach would be to have an array of addresses IDs as a field on the person, but I'd advise for the 3 tables solution.

```
persons table
1  John
2  Maria

addresses table
   1 street fake
   2 street superfake
   3 real street
   4 dark alley

 relations (person ID, address ID)
    1 1
    1 2
    1 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables should look similar to the following:

Persons:

- ID (primary key)
- Name

Addresses:

- ID (primary key)
- PersonID (this should reference the ID field on Persons)
- Address

Use a SQL statement similar to this to retrieve all the addresses for a person:

```
SELECT Address FROM Addresses WHERE Addresses.PersonID = (Person's ID).
```

Use a SQL statement similar to this to add an address:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (PersonID, Address) VALUES (Person's ID, Person's Address)
```

Comment: Thank great, but in the code what should i write when i add the select and the insert ? i mean the sql command ... etc... if you can simplify it i would really appreciate it please.